# write a function of evenNumOfOdds (L) that takes in a list of positive integers L and returns True if there are an even number of odd integers in L

Tags: python, spyder

```
                                  Test Cases:
```

Test Case                            Parameters (L)                   Return Value 
1                                     [1,2,3,6,10]                      True 
2                                    [1,3,5,7,9,10]                     False
3                                   [10,30,50,70,120]                   True (0 is even)
4                                [7,1,17,15,13,5,2,1,27,15,14,4]         False
5                                 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]           True

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to ask a good question.

Please include what you have tried so far in your question. SO is not a "code-factory" to write your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def evenNumOfOdds(list_):
return len([i for i in list_ if i%2 == 1])%2 == 0
```